# Changing Height of Div onclick

Tags: jquery, css

So I have come up with this code that changes the height of a element on click.

```
$("#container").height($("#content").height('80px'));

$('#show-1').click(function() {
    $("#container").height($("#content").height('auto')); 
});

$('#hide-1').click(function() {
    $("#container").height('99px').addClass("with-animation");    
});
```

It works just like I want, but need to apply it several different `article` elements, each with their own set of show/hide links.

My problem is I can figure out how to apply the same function to multiple element individually, without having to make a seperate function for each. Is there some way to get by `id` maybe? See the JSFiddle that I made, http://jsfiddle.net/kFUu7/1/.

Comment: FYI, `id` must be unique.

Comment: Give the required elements the same class then look into Jquery's `$(this)` functionality...it's fun.

Comment: Right, forgot to change to class.

Comment: You might also want to look into Toggle and SlideDown. Read the jQuery API...it's got tons of examples. http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want something like the following.

http://jsfiddle.net/kFUu7/6/

HTML

```
<p><a class="show click-me" id="show-1">Show</a> | <a class="hide click-me" id="hide-1">Hide</a></p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Some Random Text</h3>
        <p>Nibh minim vituperata ad duo, vix graece possim ne. Sonet alienum te pri, nam amet vidisse nonumes ei. Odio scripta signiferumque sed at, ad mucius abhorreant pri. Per eu fastidii qualisque definiebas, ea nec eirmod scribentur. Sea ut omnium suscipit, viderer dissentiunt et vix. Nibh minim vituperata ad duo, vix graece possim ne.</p>
        <p>Inani altera principes usu an, eos at congue</p>
     </div>
</div>
<p><a class="show click-me" id="show-2">Show</a> | <a class="hide click-me" id="hide-2">Hide</a></p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>More Random Text</h3>
        <p>Nibh minim vituperata ad duo, vix graece possim ne. Sonet alienum te pri, nam amet vidisse nonumes ei. Odio scripta signiferumque sed at, ad mucius abhorreant pri. Per eu fastidii qualisque definiebas, ea nec eirmod scribentur. Sea ut omnium suscipit, viderer dissentiunt et vix. Nibh minim vituperata ad duo, vix graece possim ne.</p>
        <p>Inani altera principes usu an, eos at congue dolorem corpora. Mei ne posse ocurreret, hinc tollit singulis in quo. Dico justo tincidunt no eos, id vim nisl facilisi. Nam id nisl maiorum perfecto, nam summo quando insolens ei. Te sed quis tation primis. In nec harum vituperata, eum minimum sensibus eu.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".container").height('80px');

$('.show').click(function() {
    var height = $(this).parent().next(".container").find(".content").outerHeight();
    $(this).parent().next(".container").animate({ height: height }, 500); 
});

$('.hide').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".container").animate({ height: "99px" }, 500);
});
```

CSS

```
.container {
width: 500px;
height: auto;
max-height: 9999px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #BBBBBB;
}
.click-me { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I put this all into my site. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'height' of null"

Comment: So I setup a test page with exactly the same code as the jsfiddle that you used above, but the JS does nothing. Here is the test page [http://www.klassewoodsnaturalfarm.com/KWNF/123test.php]

Comment: you haven't used the code exactly have you.... :P the problem is you have `height: "auto"` you cannot animate to `"auto"` instead you animate to the height variable you just created... `var height = $(this)... etc` you then need `height: height` in the animate statement. you could change the height variables name to make it more obvious. hope that helps and sorry for the delay, weekend! :D

Answer (score 1):

How about this, I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LVA9k/

I added "show" and "hide" classes on the anchors and changed your code to this:

```
$("#container").height($("#content").height('80px'));

$('.show').click(function() {    
    $(this).parent().next("#container").show();
});

$('.hide').click(function() {    
    $(this).parent().next("#container").hide();    
});
```

Comment: Yes this applies it to both, but it is not changing the `height` but the `display`.